# Segmentation error when trying to copy from one memory location to another

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have to code a function that reproduces the behavior of strcpy in c https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm

If I understand correctly this function, it copies a string of characters from a source memory location to a destination memory location and returns the pointer to the destination memory location.

Here the code that I have produced :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
  char *mem = dest;
  while (*src != '\0')
  {
    *dest = *src;
    src++;
    dest++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  return mem;
}

int main()
{
  char word[5] = "word";
  printf("%s \n", word);
  printf("word address is %p \n", word);
  char *dest;
  printf("dest address is %p", dest);
  ft_strcpy(dest, word);
  while (*dest != '\0'){
    printf("%c", *dest);
    dest++;
  }
}
```

To test my code I declared an array of characters word containing "word" and a pointer *dest.

However when I run my code I get a 59873 segmentation fault. I figured that it is this line responsible for the error :

```
*dest = *src;
```

However I dont understand what's wrong with this line. For me, this line means "copy the value that src pointer is pointing to into the memory location that dest is pointing to".

Could someone please explain what is going wrong with this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never give `dest` a value, so it's value is undefined. Therefore your program has undefined behavior. More specifically: `char* dest;` just gives you a "pointer to a character" but doesn't actually set the value.

```
char c = 'A';
char *dest = &c;
```

Is 100% valid code (not for your use of `dest` though). What you need is to point `dest` at a big enough chunk of memory for your purposes. You can use dynamic memory allocation:

```
dest = malloc(32); // 32 is a randomly selected value
// don't forget a NULL check and to free() once done.
```

But if you want to avoid that can of worms for now then using a static buffer will work.

```
char block[10]; // 10 is randomly selected to work in your example
char *dest = block;
```

or

```
char dest[10] = { 0 }; // initializes all to 0
// but now you can't do "dest++" etc.
```

Like:

```
int main()
{
  char word[5] = "word";
  char block[10]; // 10 is randomly selected to work in your example
  char *dest = block;

  printf("%s \n", word);
  printf("word address is %p \n", word);

  printf("dest address is %p", dest)
  ft_strcpy(dest, word);
  ...
```

Comment: thank you @john, but isnt char *dest supposed to declare a pointer and reserve a memory allocation ?

Comment: @DavidGeismar No. `char* dest` just gives you a pointer not set to anything.

Comment: I actually get an error with char dest[10] cannot increment value of type 'char [10]'

Comment: Dont change `ft_strcpy`, just change the "allocation" as shown. The problem is way back in `main` where you pass an uninitialized value to your copy function. You need to fix that.

Comment: I have tried to do as you said and allocate mem to dest using char block[10] char *dest = block. However in the end it is not printing my copied character chain as it is supposed to do in the while loop at the end of the main function...

Answer (score 1):

```
char *dest;
printf("dest address is %p", dest);
ft_strcpy(dest, word);
```

Your first issue is you're sending `dest` into `ft_strcpy` and `printf` without assigning it any value. The actual value it has is indeterminate and could well be anything.

`dest` needs to be a pointer to memory big enough to hold `word`.

```
char *dest = malloc(strlen(word) + 1)
```

If we allocate the length of `word` + 1 byte for the null terminator, `ft_strcpy` will work correctly.

Then you just need to remember to use free

```
free(dest);
```

That's it.

Your only problem was `ft_strcpy` was acting undefined by dereferencing `*dest` when `dest` was not a valid pointer.

Comment: hey @abigail I cant use any lib so I cant use malloc

Comment: then you should use the other answer above to create a static buffer, then you just have to hope that `ft_strcpy` doesn't go over it's size.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 . Your *dest is dangling pointer in main so first you need to store some valid address into it by using malloc() or other method .
2 . Storing address of string from code section in array is bad programming practice .
3 . Check the modified code .

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  /* for strcpy */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc */ 
char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)  
{  
  char *mem = dest;  
  while (*src != '\0')  
  {  
    *dest = *src;  
    src++;
    dest++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  return mem;
}

int main()
{
  char word[5]; strcpy(word,"word");
  printf("%s \n", word);
  printf("word address is %p \n", word);
  char *dest=malloc(strlen(word)+1); //+1 for null terminating character .
  printf("dest address is %p", dest);
  char *temp=dest;
  ft_strcpy(dest, word);
  while (*dest != '\0'){
    printf("%c", *dest);
    dest++;
  }
free(temp);
}
```